# PHP replace spaces with dashes in uploaded image and rename/save it?

Tags: php

I have a PHP code that I use to upload images.

This works fine. However, sometimes the images that I upload have spaces in their name like so:

```
image name.png
```

I need to do something with my PHP code that will replace the spaces in the image names with dashes like so:

```
image-name.png
```

This is my current code:

```
<?php

if(is_array($_FILES)) {

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {

$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];

$targetPath = "../../feed-images2/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];


if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {


$imageUrl = str_replace("../../","http://example-site.com/",$targetPath);



?>

<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>

<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

I tried to do something like:

```
$targetPath2 = str_replace(" ","-",$targetPath);
```

and then tried to use the variable `$targetPath2` but this is wrong.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One general clue : display (or log) your variable contents, to check if their content is fine. 
Also, did you get some error in the log ?

Comment: you're replacing spaces in `$targetpath` but you only need to replace them in `$_FILES['userImage']['name']`

Comment: @niceman you're truly a nice man. :)

Answer (score 0):

User regular expression, this can change multiple spaces or single space with hyphen.

```
$targetPath2  = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $targetPath);
```

Actually `$targetPath2 = str_replace(" ","-",$targetPath);`also works. But you have to write this code before the if condition.

```
$targetPath2  = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $targetPath);
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath2)) {

//do your stuffs

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "../../feed-images2/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
$imageUrl = str_replace(" ","-",$imageUrl);
echo $imageUrl; 
}
}
}
?>
```

Or you can use

```
$imageUrl = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $imageUrl);
```